# Fourier Transformation of 2D Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

So, I have a matrix with 72x72 values, each corresponding to some energy on a triangular lattice with 72x72 sites. I'm trying to Fourier transform the values, but I'm not understanding how to do that with `np.fft.fftn` .

To illustrate my problem I have written the following basic code with some random values. The triangular gives the lattice x,y coordinates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def triangular(nsize):
        x=0
        y=0
        X=np.zeros((nsize,nsize))
        Y=np.zeros((nsize,nsize))
        for i in range(nsize):
            for j in range(nsize):
                X[i,j]+=1/2*j+i
                Y[i,j]+=np.sqrt(3)/2*j
        return(X,Y)

xx = triangular(72)[0]
yy = triangular(72)[1]


plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, np.reshape(np.random.rand(72**2),(72,72)))
```

[image]

I'm not using random data, but I wanted not to make the example that complicated. In fact I see everytime the same plot, when I now use the following FFT:

```
matrix = []

matrix.append(triangular(72)[0])

matrix.append(triangular(72)[1])

matrix.append(np.reshape(np.random.rand(72**2),(72,72)))

spectrum_3d = np.fft.fftn(matrix)                # Fourrier transform along x, y, energy  

kx = np.linspace(-4*np.pi/3,4*np.pi/3,72)      #this is the range I want to plot

ky = np.linspace(-2*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),2*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),72)



Ky, Kx = np.meshgrid(ky, kx, indexing='ij')       #making a grid 



plt.figure(figsize=(11,9))
psd = plt.pcolormesh(Kx, Ky, abs(spectrum_3d[2])**2)
cbar = plt.colorbar(psd)
plt.xlabel('kx')
plt.ylabel('ky')
```

[image]

My result looks always the same and I don't know what went wrong. Also for my correlated values, which have a large symmetry the plot looks the same.

Comment: I don't understand the pseudo perspective in the first plot. Does it serve a reality other than looking at a 2D data set from an angle?

Comment: Likely you can solve your problem by removing the DC in the original (just subtract the average of the data). I'd plot a histogram of the spectrum and also a log histogram (small data at extremes are otherwise hard to see).

Comment: Since you are not plotting any less than all datapoints (72), why not let `np.fftfreq` do the calculation of the actual frequencies for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'see' the spectrum because of the DC dominance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

n=72
x=np.arange(n)
y=np.arange(n)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)

data=np.reshape(np.random.rand(n**2),(n,n))

data_wo_DC= data- np.mean(data)

spectrum = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(data)) 
spectrum_wo_DC = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(data_wo_DC)) 

freqx=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(72,1))   #q(n, d=1.0)
freqy=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(72,1))   
fX,fY= np.meshgrid(freqx,freqy)


p.figure(figsize=(20,6))
p.subplot(131)
p.pcolormesh(X,Y, data)  
p.colorbar()

p.subplot(132)
p.pcolormesh(fX,fY,np.abs(spectrum)) 
p.colorbar()
p.title('most data is in the DC')

p.subplot(133)
p.pcolormesh(fX,fY,np.abs(spectrum_wo_DC)) 
p.colorbar()
p.title('wo DC we can see the structure');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see now what I have done "wrong", but it doesn't answer the full question, since you didn't mention the "pseudo"-perspective". The triangular lattice is in that sense important, because it reflects the true position of the energies in xy-plane. If you would do it analytically you would have $$E_k =  \sum_j \exp(-i k r_j ) E_j$$ and the $$r$$ is a vector referencing to the triangular positions on the grid which is not the same like taking some arbitrary axis, right? How would you implement this part?

Comment: OK, so your data are a parallelogram subset of the xy-plane and zero elsewhere? In that case you could sample your triangular data in a true x,y- grid. It's best ,of course to split questions like that apart. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: That’s correct. I have only points on an equilateral triangle instead of an cubic grid. Well, it was difficult to compress the code, I tried it but maybe it wasn’t that clear.

Comment: @Leviathan So did you manage to do it for the actual triangular lattice? Did you end up implementing that part? I don't see it in your question history... I'd be interested if you did.

Comment: @Nigu Yes, but the perfomance was too slow. Therefore I asked a second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934744/loop-speed-up-of-fft-in-python-with-np-einsum