# Loop speed up of FFT in python (with `np.einsum`)

Tags: python, numpy, loops, fft, correlation

**Problem:** I want to speed up my python loop containing a lot of products and summations with `np.einsum`, but I'm also open to any other solutions.

My function takes an vector configuration S of shape (n,n,3) (my case: n=72) and does a Fourier-Transformation on the correlation function for N*N points. The correlation function is defined as the product of every vector with every other. This gets multiplied by a cosine function of the postions of vectors times the kx and ky values. Every position `i,j` is in the end summed to get one point in k-space `p,m`:

```
def spin_spin(S,N):
    n= len(S)
    conf = np.reshape(S,(n**2,3))
    chi = np.zeros((N,N))
    kx = np.linspace(-5*np.pi/3,5*np.pi/3,N)
    ky = np.linspace(-3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),N)

    x=np.reshape(triangular(n)[0],(n**2))
    y=np.reshape(triangular(n)[1],(n**2))
    for p in range(N):
        for m in range(N):
            for i in range(n**2):
                for j in range(n**2):        
                    chi[p,m] += 2/(n**2)*np.dot(conf[i],conf[j])*np.cos(kx[p]*(x[i]-x[j])+ ky[m]*(y[i]-y[j]))
    return(chi,kx,ky)
```

My problem is that I need roughly 100*100 points which are denoted by kx*ky and the loop needs to many hours to finish this job for a lattice with 72*72 vectors. 
Number of calculations: 72*72*72*72*100*100
I cannot use the built-in FFT of `numpy`, because of my triangular grid, so I need some other option to reduce here the computional cost.

**My idea:** First I recognized that reshaping the configuration into a list of vectors instead of a matrix reduces the computational cost. Furthermore I used the numba package, which also has reduced the cost, but its still too slow. I found out that a good way of calculating these kind of objects is the `np.einsum` function. Calculating the product of every vector with every vector is done with the following:

```
np.einsum('ij,kj -> ik',np.reshape(S,(72**2,3)),np.reshape(S,(72**2,3)))
```

The tricky part is the calculation of the term inside the `np.cos`. Here I want to caclulate the product between a list of shape (100,1) with the positions of the vectors (e.g. `np.shape(x)=(72**2,1)`). Especially I really dont know how to implement the distance in x-direction and y-direction with `np.einsum`.

**To reproduce the code (Probably you won't need this):** First you need a vector configuration. You can do it simply with `np.ones((72,72,3)` or you take random vectors as example with:

```
def spherical_to_cartesian(r, theta, phi):
    '''Convert spherical coordinates (physics convention) to cartesian coordinates'''
    sin_theta = np.sin(theta)
    x = r * sin_theta * np.cos(phi)
    y = r * sin_theta * np.sin(phi)
    z = r * np.cos(theta)

    return x, y, z # return a tuple

def random_directions(n, r):
    '''Return ``n`` 3-vectors in random directions with radius ``r``'''
    out = np.empty(shape=(n,3), dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(n):
        # Pick directions randomly in solid angle
        phi = random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi)
        theta = np.arccos(random.uniform(-1, 1))
        # unpack a tuple
        x, y, z = spherical_to_cartesian(r, theta, phi)
        out[i] = x, y, z

    return out
S = np.reshape(random_directions(72**2,1),(72,72,3))
```

(The reshape in this example is needed to shape it in the function `spin_spin` back to the (72**2,3) shape.)

For the positions of vectors I use a triangular grid defined by

```
def triangular(nsize):
    '''Positional arguments of the spin configuration'''

    X=np.zeros((nsize,nsize))
    Y=np.zeros((nsize,nsize))
    for i in range(nsize):
        for j in range(nsize):
            X[i,j]+=1/2*j+i
            Y[i,j]+=np.sqrt(3)/2*j
    return(X,Y)
```

Comment: Nice question. I have a few ways to start speeding it up. But first, could you clarify what is supposed to happen when you define: n= len(S) and then conf = np.reshape(S,(n**2,3))? That will always return an error, because it's trying to reshape an n X 3 matrix into an n^2 X 3 matrix.

Comment: Actually wait, I think I understand. You're feeding an array of shape (n, n, 3), not (n*n, 3)!

Comment: So actually in my own code I have a matrix with 72*72 (n=72) vectors shaped as (72,72,3). With the definition below of `random_directions` I produce directly an array of shape (n,3), so I take 72**2 to have the correct number of vectors. In the function `triangular(nsize)`  with nsize=72 I produce  two arrays X,Y of shape (72,72,1). So with your second comment you're right I feed the function with an array of shape (n,n,3) and reshape it then to (n*n,3). This reduces the number of loops, because I can use one index for all vectors not two. I will change one line in the code, then it's correct

Comment: Is float32 also enough? Should result in about 50-100s.

Comment: Yes float32 would be enough. If you meant that float32 would save 100s then that doesn't help a lot, since this code amplified by `numba` needs around 2h for N=30, but I need N=100, which I didn't get so far. I could also imagine of an solution based on `multiprocessing` or some parallized algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Optimized Numba implementation**

The main problem in your code is calling external BLAS function `np.dot` repeatedly with extremely **small** data. In this code it would make more sense to calculate them only once, but if you have to do this calculations in a loop write a Numba implementation. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774)

**Optimized function (brute-force)**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def spin_spin(S,N):
    n= len(S)
    conf = np.reshape(S,(n**2,3))
    chi = np.zeros((N,N))
    kx = np.linspace(-5*np.pi/3,5*np.pi/3,N).astype(np.float32)
    ky = np.linspace(-3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),N).astype(np.float32)

    x=np.reshape(triangular(n)[0],(n**2)).astype(np.float32)
    y=np.reshape(triangular(n)[1],(n**2)).astype(np.float32)

    #precalc some values
    fact=nb.float32(2/(n**2))
    conf_dot=np.dot(conf,conf.T).astype(np.float32)

    for p in nb.prange(N):
        for m in range(N):
            #accumulating on a scalar is often beneficial
            acc=nb.float32(0)
            for i in range(n**2):
                for j in range(n**2):        
                    acc+= conf_dot[i,j]*np.cos(kx[p]*(x[i]-x[j])+ ky[m]*(y[i]-y[j]))
            chi[p,m]=fact*acc

    return(chi,kx,ky)
```

**Optimized function (removing of redundant calculations)**

There are a lot of redundant calculations done. This is an example on how to remove them. This is also a version which does the calculations in double precision.

```
@nb.njit()
def precalc(S):
    #There may not be all redundancies removed
    n= len(S)
    conf = np.reshape(S,(n**2,3))
    conf_dot=np.dot(conf,conf.T)
    x=np.reshape(triangular(n)[0],(n**2))
    y=np.reshape(triangular(n)[1],(n**2))

    x_s=set()
    y_s=set()
    for i in range(n**2):
        for j in range(n**2):
            x_s.add((x[i]-x[j]))
            y_s.add((y[i]-y[j]))

    x_arr=np.sort(np.array(list(x_s)))
    y_arr=np.sort(np.array(list(y_s)))


    conf_dot_sel=np.zeros((x_arr.shape[0],y_arr.shape[0]))
    for i in range(n**2):
        for j in range(n**2):
            ii=np.searchsorted(x_arr,x[i]-x[j])
            jj=np.searchsorted(y_arr,y[i]-y[j])
            conf_dot_sel[ii,jj]+=conf_dot[i,j]

    return x_arr,y_arr,conf_dot_sel

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def spin_spin_opt_2(S,N):
    chi = np.empty((N,N))
    n= len(S)

    kx = np.linspace(-5*np.pi/3,5*np.pi/3,N)
    ky = np.linspace(-3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),N)

    x_arr,y_arr,conf_dot_sel=precalc(S)
    fact=2/(n**2)
    for p in nb.prange(N):
        for m in range(N):
            acc=nb.float32(0)
            for i in range(x_arr.shape[0]):
                for j in range(y_arr.shape[0]):        
                    acc+= fact*conf_dot_sel[i,j]*np.cos(kx[p]*x_arr[i]+ ky[m]*y_arr[j])
            chi[p,m]=acc

    return(chi,kx,ky)

@nb.njit()
def precalc(S):
    #There may not be all redundancies removed
    n= len(S)
    conf = np.reshape(S,(n**2,3))
    conf_dot=np.dot(conf,conf.T)
    x=np.reshape(triangular(n)[0],(n**2))
    y=np.reshape(triangular(n)[1],(n**2))

    x_s=set()
    y_s=set()
    for i in range(n**2):
        for j in range(n**2):
            x_s.add((x[i]-x[j]))
            y_s.add((y[i]-y[j]))

    x_arr=np.sort(np.array(list(x_s)))
    y_arr=np.sort(np.array(list(y_s)))


    conf_dot_sel=np.zeros((x_arr.shape[0],y_arr.shape[0]))
    for i in range(n**2):
        for j in range(n**2):
            ii=np.searchsorted(x_arr,x[i]-x[j])
            jj=np.searchsorted(y_arr,y[i]-y[j])
            conf_dot_sel[ii,jj]+=conf_dot[i,j]

    return x_arr,y_arr,conf_dot_sel

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def spin_spin_opt_2(S,N):
    chi = np.empty((N,N))
    n= len(S)

    kx = np.linspace(-5*np.pi/3,5*np.pi/3,N)
    ky = np.linspace(-3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3),N)

    x_arr,y_arr,conf_dot_sel=precalc(S)
    fact=2/(n**2)
    for p in nb.prange(N):
        for m in range(N):
            acc=nb.float32(0)
            for i in range(x_arr.shape[0]):
                for j in range(y_arr.shape[0]):        
                    acc+= fact*conf_dot_sel[i,j]*np.cos(kx[p]*x_arr[i]+ ky[m]*y_arr[j])
            chi[p,m]=acc

    return(chi,kx,ky)
```

**Timings**

```
#brute-force
%timeit res=spin_spin(S,100)
#48 s ± 671 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#new version
%timeit res_2=spin_spin_opt_2(S,100)
#5.33 s ± 59.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit res_2=spin_spin_opt_2(S,1000)
#1min 23s ± 2.43 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Edit (SVML-check)**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def foo(n):
    x   = np.empty(n*8, dtype=np.float64)
    ret = np.empty_like(x)
    for i in range(ret.size):
            ret[i] += np.cos(x[i])
    return ret

foo(1000)

if 'intel_svmlcc' in foo.inspect_llvm(foo.signatures[0]):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")

#found
```

If there is a `not found` read [this link.](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html#intel-svml) It should work on Linux and Windows, but I haven't tested it on macOS.

Comment: Also make sure that you have at least Numba 0.47 installed. In older versions there is a SVML, which can lead to a lot slower timings.

Comment: This is really great! I need about 20 min for one plot now and that's the speed up I need. Thanks a lot. I will mark it as solved if nobody comes with a better solution today.

Comment: @Leviathan If you need 20mins for a 100x100 Grid, there might be something wrong. The function 
(as shown above) shouldd only take 30s - 2min on a recent processor. A non working Intel SVML installation can lead to that.

Comment: I have numba 0.48 and an 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 with Mac OS 10.14.6. Do you know how I can install SVML?

Comment: @Leviathan I have edited the answer with a SVML- check. My timings were on a i5-8500. If the i7 is quite old (3rd gen and bellow) it could be that slow.

Comment: Indeed you was right, I hadn't the SVML. Now its about 2min. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Leviathan I have added an optimized version which reduces the amount of redundant calculations. For a small grid this would be slower, but for larger grids like (100,100) it already quite a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to speed things up. I didn't start using np.einsum because a little tweaking of your loops was sufficient.

The main thing slowing down your code was redundant recalculations of the same thing. The nested loop here is the perpetrator:

```
for p in range(N):
        for m in range(N):
            for i in range(n**2):
                for j in range(n**2):        
                    chi[p,m] += 2/(n**2)*np.dot(conf[i],conf[j])*np.cos(kx[p]*(x[i]-x[j])+ ky[m]*(y[i]-y[j]))
```

It contains a lot of redundancy, recalculating vector operations many times.

Consider the *np.dot(...)*: this calculation is completely independent of the points kx and ky. But only the points kx and ky required indexing with m and n. So you can run the dot products over all i and j just once, and save the result, as opposed to recalculating for each m,n (which would be 10,000 times!).

In a similar approach, no need for the vector differences between to be recalculated at each point in the lattice. At every point you calculate every vector distance, when all that is needed is to calculate the vector distances once and merely multiply this result by each lattice point.

So, having fixed the loops and used dictionaries with indices (i,j) as keys to store all the values, you can just look up the relevant value during the loop over i, j. Here is my code:

```
def spin_spin(S, N):
    n = len(S)
    conf = np.reshape(S,(n**2, 3))

    chi = np.zeros((N, N))
    kx = np.linspace(-5*np.pi/3, 5*np.pi/3, N)
    ky = np.linspace(-3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3), 3*np.pi/np.sqrt(3), N)

    # Minor point; no need to use triangular twice
    x, y = triangular(n)
    x, y = np.reshape(x,(n**2)), np.reshape(y,(n**2))

    # Build a look-up for all the dot products to save calculating them many times
    dot_prods = dict()
    x_diffs, y_diffs = dict(), dict()
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n**2), range(n**2)):
        dot_prods[(i, j)] = np.dot(conf[i], conf[j])
        x_diffs[(i, j)], y_diffs[(i, j)] = x[i] - x[j], y[i] - y[j]    

    # Minor point; improve syntax by converting nested for loops to one line
    for p, m in itertools.product(range(N), range(N)):
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(n**2), range(n**2)):
            # All vector operations are replaced by look ups to the dictionaries defined above
            chi[p, m] += 2/(n**2)*dot_prods[(i, j)]*np.cos(kx[p]*(x_diffs[(i, j)]) + ky[m]*(y_diffs[(i, j)]))
    return(chi, kx, ky)
```

I am running this at the moment with the dimensions you provide, on a decent machine, and the loop over i,j finishes in two minutes. That only needs to happen once; then it is just a loop over m, n. Each one of these is taking about 90 seconds, so still a 2-3 hour run time. I welcome any suggestions on how to optimise that cos calculation to speed that up!

I hit the low hanging fruit of optimization, but to give a sense of speed, the loop of i, j takes 2 minutes, and this way it runs 9,999 fewer times!

Comment: I like that you removed the redundancy out of the loops, but unfortunately this doesn't speed up as much I needed it. In fact if you take my code with all the redundancies and use `numba` then it's faster than yours and I can not use `numba` and `itertools` together, so I hope for another answer.

Comment: Really? That's surprising; I found that these changes knocked off 95% of run time. I don't have familiarity with numba, or why it might not work with itertools, but itertools was mostly for syntactic improvement anyway. For loops that small (72*72*100*100) it isn't much faster than raw for loops. So you could go back to for i in range(n): for j in range(n), and then use numba.

Comment: Yes. If you write `@jit(nopython=True)` in front of the function and use `from numba import jit` you get 294 sec for your loop and 40 sec for mine if you take only N=1 and (72,72,3) shaped matrix.

Comment: Ah okay, but will that scale as N goes up? In practice in your question you say you need N=100, which means 100*100=10,000 loops.  My code won't be any faster for N=1 because it reduced the redundancy for large N. Your code will take approximately 40*10000 seconds, mine will take less than 294 seconds to build the lookups, and some smaller amount of time per loop after that. On my machine (though I didn't wait to finish), it was looking to take approx 2-3 hours. Did you try run my code with N=100 with or without numba? Even with numba, by your numbers yours will take around 100 hours.

Comment: I'm certain my code is nowhere near maximally optimized, but I think maybe you're mistaken that it's performing slower than even the numba based solution for N=100.

Comment: So I cannot try your code with numba, because itertools is not compatible with numba. I tried your code with N=100 exactly like you have written it, but it took over 5 hours  and then I interrupted it. I can try it now for N=40 and let you know what the time for both is, when it's finished.

Comment: If you swap the two loops, looping over (i,j) in the outer loop, you can reduce the number of times  you access the lookup tables. Dictionary lookup might be slower than the cosine computation... Actually, then you can merge the first loop in, and avoid the use of dictionaries altogether.